# Обновляется ли значение переменной, если происходит операция инкремента в скобках

Tags: c++, стек

```
    bool Stack::push(const int &item)
{
    if(top<MAX)
    {
        items[top++] = item;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Меня волнует эта часть: `items[top++] = item;` top++. Меняется ли значение top глобально?  Это операция же не возвращается никуда, как программа поймет, что значение топа увеличилось? У меня представление, что стек не двигается вверх, а записывает значение на один и тот же уровень... Получается, что операция в скобках обновляет значение переменной? И если так, то не лучше ли делать ++топ, чем топ++ и аналогично с --топ

Comment: Да, естественно изменяется, но так: items[top] = item; top = top + 1;

Comment: Это получается компилятор сам заменяет мою надпись на это?

Comment: Так точно, интерпретирует именно так. ++ - это префиксный оператор увеличения

Comment: Да, конечно. Оператор всегда отрабатывает. А так items[++x] , в начале увеличивается x, а потом присваивается значение по индексу